# categorise clients in high paying, medium and low paying in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am writing a POS system for businesses and trying to categorise their clients for them in 3 major categories:

1. High paying
2. Average spend
3. Low paying

This is something that is not changing frequently so would not like to calculate it every day, may be once a month.What is the best way to handle something like this using MySQL and NodeJS. I can think of using a cron job but is there an alternative?

Edit:

1. Stay in category until significant changes is what I am looking for .
2. Secondly, about the bands,yes, that would be Top 33% of business = High Paying.

Information I am looking for:

How to determine a "Significant Change"?

Comment: This is too vague.  Do you want to recategorise them every time you run the code?  Or should someone stay in a category until something significant changes?  *(The FTSE100, for example, only relegates a company to FTSE250 when it drops to 110th position.)*  Or are you asking how to define the bands?  Would that be Top 33% of business = High Paying?  Or perhaps all the High Paying businesses add up to 33% of the total spend?  Or maybe you're just asking about the best software for scheduling an existing process (which is out of scope for SO questions)?  As I say, this is too vague, sorry.

Comment: @MatBailie: Stay in category until significant changes is what I am looking for . Secondly, about the bands,yes, that would be Top 33% of business = High Paying.

Comment: What's your question, exactly? How to write this code to categorize people?  How to determine a "Significant Change"? How to schedule this? What software to use? All of the above? The question is very vague and depending which question you are wanting answered, we may need some sample data and desired results.

Comment: @JNevill : I am looking for a pointer on "How to determine a "Significant Change"?